# Save big string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am starting to use mongodb for data storage.
In mysql I save a string of 300KB size using mysql's

```
COMPRESS(value)
```

function to save disk space.

Is there an equivalent in mongodb ?

I use python but I do not think it matters.

Also I do not want to use any compression from the programming language
 (i.e.

```
zlib.compress(value)
```

in python )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tickets about this in the [JIRA](http://jira.mongodb.org), but they are all unassigned and unresolved. Which means that (for now) you'll have to do it in the app.